# elisp function to replace text in an org file

Tags: elisp

I've made a little function for myself that replaces certain variables to text in an org file. I declare a bunch of variables in the beginning of the file and then the function replaces all references to the variable with the value. So for example

> #+VAR:location=AAAAAA
>
> text text text \v{location} text text text

becomes

> text text text AAAAAA text text text

It's my first time really playing with elisp and I'm wondering if I used the language correctly and if there's possibility to improvement.

```lisp
  (defun mp/org-fill-variables ()
    "Fill in the variables"

    (interactive)

    (let ((variable-count 0))
      (goto-char 0)

      (while (search-forward-regexp "^#\\+VAR:" nil t)

        (set-mark-command nil)
        (when (search-forward "=")

          (backward-char)
          (let ((variable (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))

            (forward-char)
            (set-mark-command nil)
            (end-of-line)
            (let ((value (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))

              ;; todo check if value non-nil
              (replace-string-in-region (concat "\\v{" variable "}") value)
              (setq variable-count (1+ variable-count))))))

      (message "replaced %d variables" variable-count)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a better `(interactive)` declaration.  Because this modifies the buffer, we want to disable it on read-only buffers.  We do that this way:

```
    (interactive "*")
```

Consider making the the function work within the active region, rather than the whole buffer:

```
  (defun mp/org-fill-variables (start end)
    "Fill in the variables"
    (interactive "*r")
```

`search-forward-regexp` is an alias for built-in function `re-search-forward`.  I would prefer the latter as that's more familiar to other programmers.  At first, I thought you had used one of the interactive functions.

We shouldn't be meddling with user's mark or position, so wrap the whole function in `(save-excursion )`, and don't use the interactive functions `(forward-char)` or `(end-of-line)`.

`(goto-char 0)` is almost always wrong.  Use `(goto-char (point-min))` so that we do the Right Thing when narrowing is in effect.

Instead of `(buffer-substring)`, we can get the variable name from the match results.  That also allows us to be more specific about what a variable name looks like (e.g. no newlines):

```
        (while (re-search-forward "^#\\+VAR:\\(.+\\)=\\(.+\\)" nil t)
          (let ((name (match-string 1))
                (value (match-string 2)))
```

Consider counting the number of replacements as well as the number of variables found.

---

Modified code:

```
  (defun mp/org-fill-variables (start end)
    "Fill in the variables."
    (interactive "*r")
    (save-excursion
      (let ((variable-count 0)
            (replacement-count 0))
        (goto-char start)
        (while (re-search-forward "^#\\+VAR:\\(.+\\)=\\(.+\\)" nil t)
          (let* ((name (match-string 1))
                 (value (match-string 2))
                 (replaced (replace-string-in-region (concat "\\v{" name "}") value
                                                     start end)))
            (setq variable-count (+ variable-count (if replaced 1 0))
                  replacement-count (+ replacement-count (or replaced 0)))))
        (message "Replaced %d variable(s) in %d location(s)"
                 variable-count replacement-count))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful and clear. I made the function like I would do when I do it myself as it started with a macro, hence the use of 'forward-char', 'search-forward-regexp', ...

Comment: I had some time to test this, but it does not work (copypasted). If no region is active it says `The mark is not active now` and when I select the whole buffer it says `End after end of buffer`. How do I start debugging this?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem with `(interactive "r")` - it requires an active region.  Perhaps make two functions, so that the buffer-wide one calls the region one with `(point-min) (point-max)` as arguments?

Comment: And the "End after end of buffer" error is a bug on my part - because we modify the buffer, that invalidates `end`.  We need to `(copy-marker end)` early on and use that marker instead.

Comment: Just to be sure. I added `(end (copy-marker end))` in the `let` variable declaration list